# Bernoulli & Binomial Random Variables Problem

Tags: probability, random-variables, solution-verification

I am attempting the following problem:

**Question**: 15% of shirts produced at a manufacturing factory are defective, what is the probability that a random sample of 6 shirts from this factory contain:

1) No defective shirts

2) At least 4 defective shirts

---

**Attempt**:

- Define X to be the number of defective products.
- P(defective shirt) = .15

**Part 1**:

- n = 6
- p = .15
- X~B(6,.15)

\begin{align}
P(X=0) & = {6 \choose 0}(.15)^0(1-.15)^{6-0}\\ \nonumber &= (1-.15)^{6}\\
\end{align}

**Part 2**:

- n = 6
- p = .15
- X~B(6,.15)

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 4) & = 1-P(X<4)\\ \nonumber &= 1-P(X=3)-P(X=2)-P(X=1)-P(X=0)\\ \nonumber &=1-{6 \choose 3}(.15)^3(1-.15)^{6-3}-{6 \choose 2}(.15)^2(1-.15)^{6-2}\\ \nonumber &-{6 \choose 1}(.15)^1(1-.15)^{6-1}-{6 \choose 0}(.15)^0(1-.15)^{6-0}\\
\end{align}

---

Comment: Your answers are correct.  In part $2$, however, computing $\ P(X\ge4)=$$P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)\ $ directly would have entailed slightly less work than subtracting $\ P(X<4)\ $ from $1$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera You are right, thank you.